# Aproximating a Sobolev function by $p$-subharmonic functions.

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded domain of class $C^2$. Take $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for $p\in (1,\infty)$ and assume that $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(x)<0,\ \forall\ x\in \partial\Omega,$$

where $\nu$ is the exterior unitary normal vector through the boundary of $\Omega$ and **I am assuming that the normal derivative does exist in the classical sense**. For $\delta>0$, define $$\Omega_\delta=\{x\in \Omega:\ \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)<\delta\},$$

where $\operatorname{dist}$ is the distance function. My question is the following:

> Can we find $\delta>0$ and a sequence $u_n\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ such that $u_n\to u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega_\delta)$ and the functions $u_n$ are $p$-subharmonic in $\Omega_\delta$, that is, $$\int _{\Omega_\delta}|\nabla u_n|^{p-2}\nabla u_n\nabla \varphi\le 0,\ \forall\ \varphi\in C_0^\infty(\Omega_\delta).$$

Any idea is appreciated. I have nothing for this problem by now.

Comment: For $u \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ the trace of the normal derivative $\partial u / \partial \nu$ is not well-defined.

Comment: What do you mean by "exists in the classical sense"? That $u$ is $C^1$ in a neighborhood of the boundary?

Comment: I mean that $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{u(x-h\nu)-u(x)}{h}>0.$$

Comment: But for $p \le N$, the point values of $u$ are not well-defined.

Comment: You are right @gerw. I have to think more on this question. Thank you for yoru time.

Comment: No problem. Does it help that you can define a normal derivative for $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ with $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't knew it. Can you give me references for it? Is it true also for the $p$-Laplacian? I mean: $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $\Delta_p u\in L^p (\Omega)$.

Comment: Let $E : H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega) \to H^1(\Omega)$ a right-inverse of the trace map. Then, you define $\partial u /\partial \nu \in (H^{1/2}(\Omega))^*$ via $\partial u/\partial \nu (v) := \int_\Omega E(v) \, \Delta u + \nabla E(v) \cdot \nabla u\,\mathrm{d}x$ for $v \in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$. This formula is motivated by integration by parts. I think it also works for $u \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, but you need $\Delta u$ (and not the $p$-Laplacian). I do not have a reference by hand, sorry.

Comment: Is your definition independente of $E$?

Comment: I think so. You might also check http://mathoverflow.net/a/109765/32507